# How to identify browser vs. backend consumers of a REST service

Tags: rest, http

**The situation**

There's a REST API which is currently consumed by other backend systems.

Now, that same REST API is going to be used by a single page application soon, and that SPA needs some additional security measures (CSRF token verification among others), but those additional security measures should be enforced only against end users running ordinary browsers, and not against other backends, so that those existing other backends keep working without any changes.

---

## The Question

How do you distinguish between when a browser is consuming a REST API and when another backend is consuming it?

Is there a header that will be sent by any modern browsers and can't be turned off or can't be tampered with?

Maybe the [`User-Agent`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/User-Agent)? Or do REST libs (in any language) send that too?

Or the `Referer`? Or `Origin`? Or some other headers?

Or something else other than a header?

Answer (score 1):

> Is there a header that will be sent by any modern browsers and can't be turned off or can't be tampered with?

As far as I know, you aren't going to find what you are looking for.

[User-Agent](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231#section-5.5.3) is close

> The "User-Agent" header field contains information about the user agent originating the request, which is often used by servers to help identify the scope of reported interoperability problems, to work around or tailor responses to avoid particular user agent limitations, and for analytics regarding browser or operating system use.  A user agent SHOULD send a User-Agent field in each request unless specifically configured not to do so.

But it certainly isn't "tamper-proof"; it's just a text header, many user agents will allow you to customize it, etc.